# VBA looping parallely through array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a loop through specifc sheets and colums which are linked specifically, but this doesn't work, am I misunderstanding how to use arrays?

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook, big, rc, sr  As Worksheet, rejcheck, copyto, arr As variant
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set big = wb.Sheets("BIG")
Set oou = wb.Sheets("OOU")
Set sr = wb.Sheets("SR")

rejcheck = Array(big, sr, oou)
copyto = Array(47, 23, 58)
arr = Array(rejcheck, copyfrom)

For Each x In arr
    With rejcheck
        .Range("a2").Copy wb.Sheets("other sheet").Cells(1, copyto)
        wb.Sheets("other sheet").Cells(1, copyto).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Name
    End With
Next x

End Sub
```

basically I want loop in a parallel fashion through these associated values `((big, 47),(sr,23),(oou,58))` having the first as the source sheet and the second the column number of a target sheet.
any help?

Comment: Hint, you `Option Explicit` at the top, it will give you so many errors in your code.

Comment: have you tested any of the solutions you got below ? are any of them work as you intended ?

Comment: hi Shai  and itslex, thank you very much for your feedback! both solutions seem to work with me, let me try resetting the code in its context. thank you very much also for point out about declarations issue! very help

Comment: update: itslex version definitely works, while Shai seems to fail as feeding the copyto. do you have any clue? thank you both again anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an array and treat it like a Worksheet. And you don't need to put the two arrays in an array. In the end, it looks like you want to do something like:

```
Option Base 0

Sub test()
  Dim wb As Workbook, big, oou, sr  As Worksheet, rejcheck, copyto, x As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set big = wb.Sheets("BIG")
  Set oou = wb.Sheets("OOU")
  Set sr = wb.Sheets("SR")

  rejcheck = Array(big, sr, oou)
  copyto = Array(47, 23, 58)

  For i = 0 To UBound(rejcheck)
    With rejcheck(i)
      .Range("a2").Copy wb.Sheets("other sheet").Cells(1, copyto(i))
      wb.Sheets("other sheet").Cells(1, copyto(i)).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Name
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually you can, use a 2-D array, 1 of worksheets and the other of numeric values. But your code works as well :)

Comment: Sure you can create that, but if `rejcheck` is an array it makes no sense to go `With rejcheck
        .Range...`

Answer (score 1):

**Variable declarations**: `big, rc, sr  As Worksheet` means `sr As Worksheet`, while `rc` and `sr` are `Variant`.Also, you are not `Dim`ing `x` anyehere. If you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code >> the VBA editor would "scream" an error.

**Next**: if you want to use `arr`, and later the loop through it in parallel, you need to define and set `arr` as a 2-D array, and read `rejcheck` and `copyto` array values to it.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim big As Worksheet, rc As Worksheet, sr As Worksheet, oou As Worksheet
Dim rejcheck As Variant, copyto As Variant, arr As Variant, x As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set big = wb.Sheets("BIG")
Set oou = wb.Sheets("OOU")
Set sr = wb.Sheets("SR")

rejcheck = Array(big, sr, oou)
copyto = Array(47, 23, 58)

' define 2-D array according to size of rejcheck array
ReDim arr(0 To UBound(rejcheck), 0 To 1)

' loop through the elements and insert to 2-d array (1 of sheets, second of numeric values)
For i = LBound(rejcheck) To UBound(rejcheck)
    Set arr(i, 0) = rejcheck(i) ' <-- use Set when adding Worksheet object
    arr(i, 1) = copyto(i)
Next i

For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    With arr(i, 0)
        .Range("A2").Copy wb.Sheets("other sheet").Cells(1, arr(i, 1))
        wb.Sheets("other sheet").Cells(1, arr(i, 1)).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Name
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```